# Cannot parse stackoverflow feed with this jquery code

Tags: jquery, rss

Using

http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/rss-feed-list/index.html (demo for tutorial http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/build-an-automated-rss-feed-list-with-jquery/)

I just added https://stackoverflow.com/feeds to the list
but it isn't parsed whereas the others are parsed correctly why ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
  <title>Automated jQuery RSS Feed Demo</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Jake Rocheleau">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/parser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="topbar"><a href="http://designshack.net">Back to Design Shack</a></div>

  <div id="w">
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Automated jQuery RSS Feed Listing</h1>

      <div id="nouperss" class="feedcontainer"></div>
      <hr>
      <div id="hongkiatrss" class="feedcontainer"></div>
      <hr>
      <div id="designmodorss" class="feedcontainer"></div>
      <hr>
      <div id="codropsrss" class="feedcontainer"></div>
    </div><!-- @end #content -->
  </div><!-- @end #w -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  parseRSS('https://stackoverflow.com/feeds', '#stackrss');
  parseRSS('http://feeds2.feedburner.com/24thfloor', '#hongkiatrss');
  parseRSS('http://feeds.feedburner.com/designmodo', '#designmodorss');
  parseRSS('http://feeds2.feedburner.com/tympanus', '#codropsrss')
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haven't looked into the matter, but what happens if you add the semicolon after the last call to `parseRSS()`? See this line: `parseRSS('http://feeds2.feedburner.com/tympanus', '#codropsrss')`.

Answer (score 0):

The SO feed is in Atom format, not RSS, so it won't be parsed properly by the ParseRSS() function.